# How to check convolution theorem in MATLAB? My result is wrong

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, convolution

I am trying to check convolution theorem in MATLAB. I have a signal called `sine_big_T`. Then I have a filter called `W`. `W` and `sine_big_T` have the same length.

The convolution theorem says that `fft(sine_big_T.*W)` should be same as the convolution of `fft(sine_big_T)` with `fft(W)`.

I am quite confused about this theorem. `fft(sine_big_T.*W)` will give me a array with length `length(sine_big_T)`. However, `conv(fft(sine_big_T), fft(W))` gives me a array with length `length(sine_big_T) + length(W) - 2`. I have tried the commend `conv(fft(sine_big_T), fft(W), 'same')`, but the result is still much different from `fft(sine_big_T.*W)`.

```
T = 128;
big_T = 8*T;
small_T = T/8;
sine_big_T = zeros(1,129);
sine_small_T = zeros(1,129);
W = zeros(1,129);
for i = 0:T
    sine_big_T(1, i+1) = sin(2*pi/big_T*i);
    W(1, i + 1) = 1 - cos(2*pi/T * i);
end


figure
plot(1:129,fft(sine_big_T.*W));

I_fft = fft(sine_big_T);
W_fft = fft(W);
test = conv(I_fft, W_fft,'same');
figure
plot(1:length(I_fft), test)
```

From the theorem, the two plots should look same. But the result is not even close. I think the way I use `conv` is not correct. What is the right way to verify the theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `conv` with `'same'` is correct. You are seeing two things:

1. `fft` defines the origin in the first array element, not the middle of the domain. This does not play well with `conv`. Use this instead:

   ```matlab
   test = ifftshift( conv( fftshift(I_fft), fftshift(W_fft), 'same' ) );
   ```

   The `fftshift` function shifts the origin to the middle of the array, where it is good for `conv` with `'same'`, and `ifftshift` shifts the origin back to the first element.
2. Normalization. The FFT is typically normalized so that multiplication in the frequency domain is convolution in the spatial domain. Since you are computing convolution in the frequency domain, the normalization is off. To correct the normalization, plot

   ```matlab
   plot(1:129,fft(sine_big_T.*W)*length(W));
   ```